# MacBook Pro freezing a few programs (different each time) before resuming?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro that is running OS 10.7.5 -- and it's behaving very strangely. I'm actually at a loss as to what to even search for. The best I can do is to link to a video I took of the laptop while it was behaving this way:

http://youtu.be/llTyJvfzItA

Summary of the behavior I'm seeing:

For about 10 minutes at a time, my computer will freeze 2 or 3 programs (they aren't always the same programs). Other programs can work without issue. After ~10 minutes everything suddenly starts working again (and actions that were attempted all get executed rapidly).

All of that behavior is shown in the video (see it start working again right at the end).

Weird things:

1. Chrome thinks that certain tabs are dead because it isn't getting a heartbeat (so it offers to kill the tab). Doing so, or not doing so does not matter.
2. The CPU and memory usage remains near idle level.
3. Only some programs are affected (because of this repeated behavior I've switched to Netscape and back to Chrome; from Textmate to Sublime Text; in attempts to isolate what could be happening.
4. If I'm playing music through itunes, for example, sometimes when it freezes, it will halt the music until it resumes. Other times, it will continue to work.

Any help on figuring out what to do and what's causing it would be much appreciated!

### EDIT

By request here is the Console log around the time of the problem (I began filming at 17:46 so the problems around 17:40 are probably suspect) :

```
2014-05-05 17.40.12 5:40:12.474 PM com.jamfsoftware.task.Every 30 Minutes: Delaying 198 seconds...
2014-05-05 17.40.28 5:40:28.316 PM Evernote: CoreData: error:  (External Records Support): symlink from path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/Evernote/jbwhitmore/Evernote.sql to path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “store-file” couldn’t be saved in the folder “.support” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x118ba9050 {NSFilePath=/Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file, NSUnderlyingError=0x1116b1200 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
2014-05-05 17.40.42 5:40:42.745 PM com.apple.backupd: Starting standard backup
2014-05-05 17.40.42 5:40:42.889 PM Evernote: CoreData: error:  (External Records Support): symlink from path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/Evernote/jbwhitmore/Evernote.sql to path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “store-file” couldn’t be saved in the folder “.support” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x10442b000 {NSFilePath=/Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file, NSUnderlyingError=0x10444cbb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
2014-05-05 17.40.43 5:40:43.705 PM com.apple.backupd: Error -35 while resolving alias to backup target
2014-05-05 17.40.44 5:40:44.000 PM kernel: nspace-handler-set-snapshot-time: 1399275645
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: [EWOULDBLOCK][vnode:0xffffff801f261d90][original:0xffffff801f261d90][callback: 0 count:265 ] onaccessctl_check:1825 result:0 disconnected:0
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: current scan list:
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: (pid 564 [mtmd], vnode 0xffffff801f261d90 [/Users/jwhitmore/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Session Storage/008623.log], [context 0xffffff8015d96050] [result 0] [setup 0] [disconnected 0] [vfsbusy 0]) - 1 waiter(s)
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: available kctl entries: 9
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: NULL target or context; request:0 kctl_entry:0xffffff801c359000
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: not SAV_KCTL_REQ_COMPLETE, return ENOMEM
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: NULL target or context; request:0 kctl_entry:0xffffff801c359000
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: not SAV_KCTL_REQ_COMPLETE, return ENOMEM
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: NULL target or context; request:3 kctl_entry:0xffffff801c359000
2014-05-05 17.50.45 5:50:45.000 PM kernel: sav: onaccess_send: SAV_KCTL_REQ_COMPLETE, intercheck_done()
2014-05-05 17.50.46 5:50:46.066 PM com.apple.backupd: Backup failed with error: 19
2014-05-05 17.50.47 5:50:47.000 PM kernel: nspace-handler-unblock: did not find token 167909
2014-05-05 17.50.48 5:50:48.977 PM Evernote: CoreData: error:  (External Records Support): symlink from path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/Evernote/jbwhitmore/Evernote.sql to path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “store-file” couldn’t be saved in the folder “.support” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x118659780 {NSFilePath=/Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file, NSUnderlyingError=0x11c088100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
2014-05-05 17.50.49 5:50:49.254 PM com.jamfsoftware.task.Every 30 Minutes: Checking for policies triggered by "recurring check-in"...
2014-05-05 17.50.51 5:50:51.758 PM com.jamfsoftware.task.Every 30 Minutes: No policies were found for the "recurring check-in" trigger.
2014-05-05 17.50.57 5:50:57.923 PM Evernote: CoreData: error:  (External Records Support): symlink from path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/Application Support/Evernote/accounts/Evernote/jbwhitmore/Evernote.sql to path /Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “store-file” couldn’t be saved in the folder “.support” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x11b6e51c0 {NSFilePath=/Users/jwhitmore/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/Data/Library/CoreData/com.evernote.Evernote/24458A30-8292-4A14-8D69-EFBA68CA25EE/.support/store-file, NSUnderlyingError=0x118b8ad90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
2014-05-05 17.51.16 5:51:16.000 PM kernel: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=35417[GoogleSoftwareUp] clearing CS_VALID
2014-05-05 17.52.32 5:52:32.240 PM com.apple.kextd: Can't create kext cache under / - owner not root.
2014-05-05 17.52.32 5:52:32.522 PM com.apple.usbmuxd: Ignored device, IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed: 0xe00002be
2014-05-05 17.52.43 5:52:43.968 PM SophosWebD: <SMENode: 0x7fcc2a62d000> localNode csc:1ERROR! encountered an error while writing to outputstream| error:Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=32 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Broken pipe" UserInfo=0x7fcc2ba03db0 {}
2014-05-05 17.53.19 5:53:19.232 PM iTunes: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:32
```

Actually that looks like it might have a few clues.

Comment: would you consider upgrading to Mavericks? if not then you need to repair your OS.

Comment: if you are familiar with it, open the Console located in your utility folder, and copy few lines around the time stamp of the problem so we can have a look.

Comment: I updated the question with the requested info.

Comment: great, so first disable your backup for now

Comment: OK, I've turned off Time Machine (hopefully that's what you mean).

Comment: Also, I've opened a new question related to your suggestion to upgrade to Mavericks which details the problems I'm having there: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129688/weird-restriction-keeping-me-from-updating-to-mavericks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Console log you published there are 2 sore thumbs sticking out.

1. Your Time Machine backup is having some problems.

   Turn off the Time Machine backup for a while to see if the problem gets better.
2. jamfsoftware.task

   Disable the JAMF software task (or the entire software).

Please post new question to resolve your TM problems.

Answer (score 0):

That 10 minute freeze sounds familiar. Could be related to Sophos 9. Apparently there "is a built-in "last ditch" timeout in the on-access scanner [of Sophos] that is exactly ten minutes long." [Source.](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Sophos-9-causes-Mavericks-to-freeze/td-p/14893/page/7)

Only thing is, recent reports about this issue are all about Mavericks...

Comment: How could it be Sophos?