# Weird restriction keeping me from updating to Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have tried to install Mavericks on my MacBook Pro 10.7.5 laptop. It has some software that was added by well-meaning enterprise IT people.

Here's what I see after downloading and attempting to install Mavericks:

[image: Error message: Installation of Mavericks using a download from the Apple App Store is not permitted at this stage.]

I would like to force this update to happen, but I can't figure out how to make it happen. I should add that I do have root access. Any suggestions appreciated!

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments, this error message is almost certainly not from Apple. I agree with this, as when I first encountered this error message upon trying to install the Mavericks upgrade I copied the text verbatim into Google and found nothing.

So the question, now, is can I, as a user with root access, force an installation of Mavericks? It seems in principle that it should be possible. However, I have no foggy idea how to make it happen.

Comment: are you sure you can update from 10.7 to 10.9?
I'm guessing you need to go to 10.8 first to be able to download the free mavericks update

Comment: @JBWhitmore Is your mac compatible? https://www.apple.com/uk/osx/how-to-upgrade/

Comment: Just curious, why haven't you contacted the well-meaning enterprise IT people? That might be the best place to start. Is the Mac a corporate asset? Are you sure you should be doing what you're trying to do?

Comment: @dennismuys One can update to Mavericks for free *from 10.6* directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message shown in the screenshot is almost certainly not an Apple official message for two reasons: they never refer to the Mac App Store as the 'Apple App Store' and the icon/text layout isn't correct per any other OS X message I've seen.

The most likely cause of the restriction is the **JAMF MDM software** installed on your Mac (based on the log from your last question).

Therefore, the software that is preventing Mavericks install can't prevent it if you're not booted into that OS. You should be able to create an install media using [**DiskMakerX**](http://diskmakerx.com/). Then, boot into this install media and install Mavericks that way.

Comment: This sounds really promising and I've +1'ed it. I will probably try it this weekend and if it works I'll mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: @JBWhitmore Ping: edited answer — just read the log from your last question and have a plausible app :) I had suspicions it may be JAMF, but didn't want to throw accusations at software that the average user doesn't have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a backup, then boot the Mac holding Command and R and then follow [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph4439) instruction.